# Detect date or datetime format java

Tags: java, date, datetime

EDIT: I posted a wrong problem. Screw my brain.

I have a this input from a webpage

`02-01-2014 12:00 AM`

Basically, after the input goes to the `ReportServiceImpl`, the class converts the string input to `Date` type.

`private SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a");`

Now, due to change of requirements, I have to remove the time. I can easily alter the line above, but that simple change will cascade to the whole system and I have to replace a handful of lines and methods for this format to work.

The solution that I'm thinking is, accept both `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a` and `MM-dd-yyyy`, but how can I detect the input format?

Thoughts?

EDIT:

I don't like this approach at all. Is there an alternative for this?

```
 public Date fmtDate(String date) throws Exception {
      DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
      DateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

      try {
           return dateFormat1.parse(date);
      } catch(Exception e) {
           return dateFormat2.parse(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. You want only the date, but then you also want the date + time; also you are talking about `String` input, but the code you show takes a `Date`. Do you understand this doesn't make sense?

Comment: If I understand your question properly then you are looking for `Date` object from `String`. You can use `parse()` of `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question correctly, but maybe you can detect the format just by it's length? Sry if this is not what you are searching for

Comment: What do you not like about your approach? I think it does make sense. And I could understand it with no problems. So it is comprehensible as well ;)

Comment: How do you know those are the only two formats the date might be in?  What I'd probably do is create a method that attempts to derive the format string, probably using Regex, then use those results to try.  If you know a specific example _has_ to be a given format, just use that outright (don't bother with the current method in that case).  Oh, and just a reminder that `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread-safe.